# Not able to add border-color to my nav bar or header

Tags: css, colors, flexbox

I want to give my nav-bar a border-color but it is not applying on both "nav" tag and "header" tag.

Can anyone please help me out through this?

```
nav {
    background-color: #004c3f;
    border-color: black;
    color: aliceblue;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add also the `border-width` and `border-style`.
But you can use the shorter `border:1px solid black;`
[Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border)

```css
nav {
    /*background-color: #004c3f;*/
    border-color: black;
    border-width:1px;
    border-style:solid;
    color: aliceblue;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding:10px;
  }
```

```html
<nav>
</nav>
```